# Can LDTP automate Qt-based applications?

Tags: automated-testing

We are building an application, which is based on [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29) 4.8 on Windows. I have been looking for an automation tool which is cross-platform and should be able to automate my application. I have read a few papers about [Linux Desktop Testing Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Desktop_Testing_Project) (LDTP), so I am interested to know whether tool can be of any help to me?

Comment: Welcome to SQA! Can you expand LDTP abbreviation and provide link to it and papers describing it? I guess this might be informative to people new to this topic.

Comment: You need to have QT version >= 4.8 for LDTP to recognize

Comment: I just finished not big automated test with LDTP for QT Application. It was not difficult - read a documentation of LDTP and do it. Documentation has a lot examples.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used [QTestLib](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-manual.html#qtestlib). It has all the basic functionality of a test automation framework and is designed for Qt applications.

Answer (score 0):

I've no real experience with QT on Windows or LDTP, but did a quick search and found that if I'm right that you mean [Linux Desktop Testing Platform](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/), it specifically mentions that it can be used to test QT on Windows XP SP3, albeit, with its windows version, named [Cobra](https://github.com/ldtp/cobra).

Comment: It seems like there aren't many accessible resources on how to write tests using it!